# Background color and background img on Hover table cell

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a table that is made from div and setting the display to table,table-row,table-cell. On these table cells (except the nth-child(1) ) I have a background image with a grey line which I set it to the entire cell exactly as shown on the screenshot below. Now this is a bit advanced css techniques for me as I am not really a web designer but rather a software engineer however I need the background color of the row to turn grey since the background of the image is white, however it does not. If I didnt explain well, my screenshot below show the desired effect. My question is only based on how I do that ON HOVER effect.

My html code sample is like this

```
<div class="tableName">
 <div class="tableRow">
  <div class="tableCell">
   <span><!--random data --></span>
  </div>
  <div class="tableCell">
   <span><!--random data --></span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And my css code below

```
.trafficTable{
   display:table;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width:100%;
 }
.trafficRow{
   display:table-row;
   width:100%;
}
.trafficRow:nth-child(1){
  color:#FFFFFF;
}
.trafficCell{
  display:table-cell;
  border:1px solid #b3b3b3;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:13.5%;
  font-size:13px;
  background-image:url("/images/strike.png");
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-color:#424F90;
  cursor:pointer;
 }
 .trafficCell:nth-child(1){
   width:5%; 
  background-image: none !important;
  color:#FFFFFF;cursor:default;
}
 .trafficRow:nth-child(1) .trafficCell{
   background-color:#F79B2E !important;
   background-image: none !important;
   cursor:default;
 }
 .trafficRow:nth-child(1) .trafficCell:hover{
    background-color:#F79B2E !important;
 }
  .trafficRow:nth-child(1):hover{
     background-color:#F79B2E !important;
 }
  .trafficCell:hover{background-color:#BA0C2F !important;}
  .trafficCell:nth-child(1):hover{background-color:#424F90 !important;}
  .trafficRow:hover::before{
    background-color:#e6e6e6 !important;
    content: '';
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
  }


  .trafficCell span{
    display:inline-block;
    min-height: 182px; 
    width:100%;
   font-weight:900;
 }
```

Please note that obviously the class names match the css names. The answer must not be done with opacity please. I have tried numerous things including the technique I found here (the only one about closest to this scenario I am facing) with the ::before pseudo selector, still did not work.

The desired effect screenshot as promised :
[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJKJr.png)

Edit: I guess people missunderstood my question. The desired effect shown on the screenshot is shows the desired effect ON HOVER. I know that you cant hover oin table cells until CSS4 is out and parent selector is out and thats why i will do that with javascript/jquery, basically what I am asking is why the background-color gets overwritten from the background img even thoough the background of the image is white so it shouldn't have any effect???

Comment: I think this would be much simpler if done with JS rather than CSS, is that an option?

Comment: Why not use an actual table instead of divs? You could style the `<col>` tag.

Comment: You can use a transparent PNG image (just the line) and a background color (that change on hover).